# '@' appearing when inserting formula with vba in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to insert a formula into a cell using VBA.
This one code works just fine:

```vb
Range("C6").FormulaLocal = "=SI(AI6<>"""";""Dictaminado"";SI(O(AB6<>"""";AC6<>"""");""En Dictamen"";SI(AA6<>"""";""Recibido"";""Pend. Pack"")))"
```

The problem is with this other code:

```vb
Range("D6").FormulaLocal = "=SI(O(E6:I6="""";K6="""";N6:O6="""";Q6:S6="""";Y6="""";AA6:AC6="""";AE6:AF6="""";AH6:AK6="""");""Miss. Info"";""Complete"")"
```

In Excel an `@` appears in front of every range in the formula like this:

```
=SI(O(E6="";K6="";@N6:O6="";@Q6:S6="";Y6="";@AA6:AC6="";@AE6:AF6="";@AH6:AK6="");"Miss. Info";"Complete")
```

And it throws a `#VALUE` error. Can someone explain why is this happening and how to avoid it?

Comment: Appears to be an array formula. So FormulaArray? But don't forget that wont take local written formats...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [@JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61269296/appearing-when-inserting-formula-with-vba-in-excel#comment108389568_61269296) for your comment!

> Appears to be an array formula. So FormulaArray? But don't forget that wont take local written formats...

I solved it doing this:

```
Range("D6").FormulaLocal = [here goes the formula]
Range("D6").FormulaArray = Range("D6").Formula
```